# Data from power BI desktop comes different when I import into power bi report builder

Tags: powerbi, reportbuilder

When I import a measure from power bi report builder, it gives a totally different value than my report, even using the same filters. It seems that the data arrives altered. Is it because I'm using a measure?

On the bi desktop, my column "oil" is giving 19,430.19
In the report builder, the same measure is giving 58,000.00

I'm using the same filters on both

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask